# How to grep for a line above a previously matched line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have log files in which the date is only appended periodically. My log file looks something like this:

```
Monday 2017
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

I am making a script that goes something like this:

```
grep 'ALARM' myfile.log | tail -1
```

I need to search for the previous date entry above the last alarm and include that in my results. I have no idea how many lines above the matched alarm line it will occur.

Desired output:

```
Monday 2017
foo foo foo foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo
```

Comment: This is probably a job for something more powerful than `grep`.  If the date was always a specified number of lines above, you could maybe do (for example) `grep -B10 'ALARM' myfile.log | grep 'Monday'`, but even that solution has a number of flaws.

Comment: How  can you tell that a line is a date entry? Is it the only indented line?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Monday 2017 doesn't seem to be a date, can you give the date pattern also please?

Answer (score 2):

assuming date pattern is `Monday 2017`

```
grep -E 'Monday 2017|ALARM' | grep -B1 'ALARM'
```

second grep is to remove multiple date pattern between ALARM matches,

EDIT: reading again question it seems only the last line matching ALARM is wanted, I would do with following perl one liner:

```
perl -ne 'if(/Monday 2017/){$last_date=$_}if(/ALARM/){$date=$last_date;$line=$_}END{print $date,$line}' <<END
Monday 2017
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tac` to reverse a stream line-by-line (see `seq 10 | tac` to see what it does).  This is not cheap, be warned, but if your stuff is small enough, this can provide an simple solution:

```
grep -B 9999999 lastSearchTerm my.log | tac | grep -B 9999999 firstSearchTerm | tac
```

This will print the block from the firstSearchTerm to the lastSearchTerm.

```
grep -B 9999999 lastSearchTerm my.log | tac | tail -n +2 | grep -m 1 lastBeforeTerm
```

This will print only the last line containing lastBeforeTerm before the lastSearchTerm.

For your specific case, this should do it:

```
grep -B 9999999 ALARM my.log | tac | {
  IFS= read -e line
  grep -m 1 '2017'
  echo "$line"
}
```

(Adjust the `2017` part to match any line which looks like a time stamp.)

Of course, this is not the fastest solution but it is simple and will work for small input.

Comment: This works awesome for me! I wasn't familiar with tac, and I don't know what IFS= is doing, but thanks.  I have to check out some other responses, but this one is working for my needs.  I changed the  -B to 300 as it probably wont be further than that.  The entire log is less that 3000 lines at a time usually before it is archived.

Comment: `IFS` is the internal field separator, a variable influencing how `read` works (and other things).  Setting it to <empty> makes `read` read a complete line without handling spaces and the like specially.  Also the option `-e` makes `read` handle backslashes without any special meaning.  The pattern `IFS= read -e line` just says:  read one line verbatim, without stripping spaces or interpreting backslashes or the like.

Comment: I had it working on my test machine, but when I put it on the server, it wouldn't work.  Turns out the server has an older version of grep that doesn't support the -m option.  So I modified it, and it is working now (unless I can streamline this somehow). 

`fail_recov () {
clear
echo
echo "Locations last Failure/Recovery:"
grep -E '2017|2018|AlarmString' myfile.log >test.tmp
grep -B 100 'AlarmString' test.tmp| tac | {
  IFS= read -e line
  grep '2018\|2017' | head -1
  echo "$line"
}
rm -f test.tmp`

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** + **`tac`** solution:

Sample `myfile.log` contents:

```
some text text text
Sunday 2017
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
bar foo foo foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo
bar foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
Monday 2017
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo
text foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

---

The job:

```
awk '/ALARM/{ f=1 }f && /^[A-Z][a-z]+ 2[0-9]{3}/{ print; exit }' <(tac myfile.log)
```

- `tac myfile.log` - print the file lines in reverse
- `/ALARM/{ f=1 }` - on encountering `ALARM` line - set the starting phase of the processing using the flag `f`
- `/^[A-Z][a-z]+ 2[0-9]{3}/` - pattern indicating *"date"* line
- `print; exit` - print the current line(as a resulting line) and terminate script execution immediately

The output:

```
Monday 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that a "date" is characterized by a line containing `day` and four digits:

```
tac myfile.log \
    | sed -En '/ALARM/,/day [[:digit:]]{4}/{/day [[:digit:]]{4}/{p;q}}'
```

Like the other solutions, this uses `tac` to print the lines in reverse; the sed command then does this:

`-n` suppresses output by default.

```
/ALARM/,/day [[:digit:]]{4}/ { # In the range from ALARM to the date
    /day [[:digit:]]{4}/{      # On the line of the date
        p                      # Print just that line
        q                      # Exit
    }
}
```

The `q` is there to avoid reading the rest of the file after we've already found what we wanted.

Notice that some seds might need extra semicolons, as in `{p;q;}`.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution,

```
awk 'NF==2 {d=$0}; /ALARM/ { printf("%s\n%s\n", d, $0)}' sample.txt
```

output:

```
Monday 2017
foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
Monday 2017
foo foo foo foo foo foo ALARM foo foo foo foo foo
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't do this efficiently with Grep. Here's a simple Sed construct to remember:

```
sed -n '/before/ {h;n;}; /after/ {x;p;x;p;}' < input.txt
```

This stores the most recent line matching the pattern `before` and then prints it out whenever it encounters a subsequent line matching the pattern `after`. Then, it prints out the line matching `after` as well. To break it down:

- The `-n` flag suppresses output of every line—we'll tell Sed to output what we want manually.
- `/before/` - When we find a line matched by the pattern `before`...

  - `h` - Save it to the hold space buffer for later.
  - `n` - Proceed to the next line.
- `/after/` - When we find a line matched by the pattern `after`...

  - `x;p` - Exchange the line with the contents of the hold buffer (`before`) and print it.
  - `x;p` - Swap `after` back out of the hold buffer and print it.

This runs very quickly because we can filter the input in one pass without the need to pipe the output or reverse the file first.

---

Now, let's apply it to the example in the question:

```
sed -n '/^date pattern$/ {h;n;}; /ALARM/ {x;p;x;p;}' < input.txt
```

This just plugs the specific patterns into the Sed program that I described above—it outputs the most recently seen date and the matched line every time it sees `ALARM`. Because the question only wants to show the *last* line containing `ALARM` after each date, we need to modify the program slightly:

```
sed -n '
    /^date pattern$/ {
        :alarm
        x
        /ALARM/ {s/^\(date pattern\)\n.*\n\(.*ALARM.*\)$/\1\n\2/;p;n;}
    }
    /ALARM/ H
    $ b alarm
' < input.txt
```

Instead of holding just the date line, this buffers the date *and* each of the lines containing `ALARM` until Sed encounters the next date, after which it will print the the date and the last `ALARM` line in the hold buffer. We check for the presence of `ALARM` so we don't print a date when no alarms occurred. `:alarm` declares a branch label that we can return to using `b alarm` as we do for the last line of the file (denoted by `$`) to handle anything leftover in the hold space buffer.

I used `[A-Z][a-z]\+day [0-9]\{4\}` for `date pattern` in each of these examples, but adjust as needed.

**Edit:** I think I misread the question. It looks like we only want the last date and the last alarm line from the *entire* file. If this is true, using Tac to reverse the file first is faster, but consumes more memory:

```
tac input.txt | sed -n '/ALARM/ {h;:a;n;/^date pattern$/ {p;x;p;q;}; ba;}'
```

With this approach, we store the last alarm in the file and print it after we find and print the last date in the file. We use `q` to exit as soon as we find the last date to avoid processing the rest. If we don't have Tac on our system, we can use Sed to reverse a file as well:

```
sed '1!G;h;$!d' < input.txt | sed ...
```